# Best way to implement custom controller "/schema" function using Spring Data REST?

Tags: customization, spring-data-rest

What is the best way to implement "**/schema**" function on custom controllers (explained in  [rest-bucks](https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springsource/restbucks/payment/web/PaymentController.java) ) similar to "**[repository]/schema**" function with Spring Data Rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If entity classes are persisted through Spring Repositories, the solution is to inject `PersistentEntityToJsonSchemaConverter` into the controller and invoke `convert()` method.

Below is a code sample using Mongo as Repository

**Entity class**

```
@Document
    public class Project implements Identifiable<String> {

        @Id
        private String id;

    @NotNull
        private String name;
    //getters setters
    }
```

**Repository**

```
public interface ProjectRepository extends
        PagingAndSortingRepository<Project, String> {
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@ExposesResourceFor(Project.class)
@RequestMapping("/projects")
public class ProjectController {
@Autowired
    private PersistentEntityToJsonSchemaConverter jsonSchemaConverter;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/schema", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/schema+json" })
    @ResponseBody
    public JsonSchema schema() {
        return jsonSchemaConverter.convert(Project.class);
    }
// implement rest of SDR mechanics

}
```